# Compiling with Libadwaita, GTK4 and C

Tags: gnome, dependencies, compiling

After installing the libadwaita-1-dev package on Ubuntu 23.10, I tried to compile the example from the [official documentation](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/main/initialization.html):

```
 gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4) $(pkg-config –-cflags --libs libadwaita-1) hello-adwita.c -o hello
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work.
The error message is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccNMYti.o: in function `glib_autoptr_clear_GtkApplication':
hello-adwita.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cccNMYti.o: in function `activate_cb':
hello-adwita.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `gtk_application_window_new'
/usr/bin/ld: hello-adwita.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `gtk_label_new'
/usr/bin/ld: hello-adwita.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: hello-adwita.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/usr/bin/ld: hello-adwita.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `gtk_window_set_title'
/usr/bin/ld: hello-adwita.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_type'
…
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the order in which your `gcc` command expands the required libraries. In particular, symbols are resolved from left to right, so if your code depends on `libawaita-1` and `libawaita-1` depends in turn on the `gtk-4` libraries, the order should be

```
hello-adwaita.c   <---  libadwaita-1   <--- libgtk-4
```

So

```
gcc hello-adwaita.c -o hello $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libadwaita-1) $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4)
```

However in this case, the output of `pkg-config --libs libadwaita-1` contains libgtk4 and all its dependent libraries, so all you should need is

```
gcc hello-adwaita.c -o hello $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libadwaita-1)
```

For further information see

- [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid compiler command line: you are passing compiler and linker flags at the same time, and in the wrong place. The compiler flags go first, followed by the output file and the input one; then, you need to pass the linker flags:

```
gcc ${compiler_flags} -o ${output} ${input} ${linker_flags}
```

You are also duplicating the GTK compiler and linker flags: libadwaita depends on GTK already.

To sum up:

```
gcc $( pkg-config --cflags libadwaita-1 ) -o hello hello.c $( pkg-config --libs libadwaita-1)
```